# Convert a Pandas DataFrame with true/false to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I would like to transform a dataframe with the following layout:

```
|  image  | finding1 | finding2 | nofinding |

| ------- | -------- | -------- | --------- |
| 039.png |   true   |   false  |   false   |
| 006.png |   true   |   true   |   false   |
| 012.png |   false  |   false  |   true    |
```

into a dictionary with the following structure:

```
{
  "039.png" : [
    "finding1"
  ],
  "006.png" : [
    "finding1",
    "finding2"
  ],
  "012.png" : [
    "nofinding"
  ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could replace the False to NA (assuming boolean False here, for strings use 'false'), then `stack` to remove the values and use `groupby.agg` to aggregate as list before converting to dictionary:

```
dic = (df
 .set_index('image')
 .replace({False: pd.NA})
 .stack()
 .reset_index(1)
 .groupby(level='image', sort=False)['level_1'].agg(list)
 .to_dict()
)
```

output:

```
{'039.png': ['finding1'],
 '006.png': ['finding1', 'finding2'],
 '012.png': ['nofinding']}
```